# How can i reduce the image size in html page?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, image, uiwebview

I have one simple html with following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="English">
    <head>
        <link href="../Styles/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Image</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @page 
            {
                margin: 0; 
                padding: 0; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; oeb-column-number: 1;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;"><img alt="main" id="mainImage" src="../images/Image.jpg" style="height: 100%; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;" /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In a folder I have `Image.jpg` file

Is that possible to add a css rule using Objective-C and change the `img` tag width and height? please help me.

I tried this code but it not working for me.

```
NSString *setImageRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('img', 'max-width: %fpx; height: %fpx;')", self.webView.frame.size.width*0.75,self.webView.frame.size.height*0.75];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setImageRule];
```

Comment: why are you using css in your html? use a stylesheet instead.

Comment: I think just set width and height will help, don't them?

Comment: no i have to inject this code here,other wise rest of my project wont work

Comment: @KeesSonnema how can i add css externally?

Comment: add it to your design.css; why have a stylesheet, a styles tag and inline styles?

Comment: please tell me corrctly

Answer (score 1):

if you want to resize the UIImage,you can simply access the folder where the image is stored and resize it. Use this code for example :

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: no the html already giving some width and height so i have to override that one